# How to save my own trained word embedding model (Using Keras) like word2vec and Glove

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, word-embedding

I trained my own word embedding model using my own data set. Now, after training the Keras Embeddings layer,  I want to save the model in a text file so I can use for later classification of the unknown data set.

**Source Code**: https://machinelearningmastery.com/use-word-embedding-layers-deep-learning-keras/#comment-507619:

```
from numpy import array
from keras.preprocessing.text import one_hot
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers.embeddings import Embedding
# define documents
docs = ['Well done!',
        'Good work',
        'Great effort',
        'nice work',
        'Excellent!',
        'Weak',
        'Poor effort!',
        'not good',
        'poor work',
        'Could have done better.']
# define class labels
labels = array([1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0])
# integer encode the documents
vocab_size = 50
encoded_docs = [one_hot(d, vocab_size) for d in docs]
print(encoded_docs)
# pad documents to a max length of 4 words
max_length = 4
padded_docs = pad_sequences(encoded_docs, maxlen=max_length, padding='post')
print(padded_docs)
# define the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, 8, input_length=max_length))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
# compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
# summarize the model
print(model.summary())
# fit the model
model.fit(padded_docs, labels, epochs=50, verbose=0)
# evaluate the model
loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(padded_docs, labels, verbose=0)
print('Accuracy: %f' % (accuracy*100))
```

However, I tried to save the model using a different format (.txt),

```
model.save('My_Model.txt')
```

however, the problem is that when I open the file, the data seems to have weird characters.

I also got Embedding weights  by this:

[image]

How I could save my model in the same format of Glove and word2vec, the word followed by its vector..?

Please guide me, how to save it like

the  -6.07421696e-02, -3.59963439e-02,  4.38806415e-02, -3.08707543e-02, -1.51436431e-02, -5.56904338e-02, 5.70665635e-02, -8.34236890e-02

Answer (score 2):

As I understand you don't need to save exactly the model, but need to save *pre-trained embeddings*. I a bit adjust your code:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing.text import one_hot, Tokenizer
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers.embeddings import Embedding

# define documents
docs = np.array(['Well done!',
        'Good work',
        'Great effort',
        'nice work',
        'Excellent!',
        'Weak',
        'Poor effort!',
        'not good',
        'poor work',
        'Could have done better.'])
# define class labels
labels = np.array([1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0])

# train the tokenizer
vocab_size = 50
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=vocab_size)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(docs)

# encode the sentences
encoded_docs = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(docs)
print(encoded_docs)

# pad documents to a max length of 4 words
max_length = 4
padded_docs = pad_sequences(encoded_docs, maxlen=max_length, padding='post')
print(padded_docs)

# define the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, 8, input_length=max_length, name='embeddings'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

# compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# fit the model
model.fit(padded_docs, labels, epochs=50, verbose=0)

# save embeddings
embeddings = model.get_layer('embeddings').get_weights()[0]
w2v_my = {}

for word, index in tokenizer.word_index.items():
    w2v_my[word] = embeddings[index]

print(w2v_my['good'])
```

Please note, that you can find embeddings only for the words, that were present in the training dataset. In the current example, you will not find the embeddings for the word *"the"*.

If you need to be able to get embeddings for unknown words, you can use Tokenizer with **char_level**.

To be able to store and re-use embeddings you can use numpy:

```
np.savez('embeddings.npz', **w2v_my)
embeddings = np.load('embeddings.npz')

# check existing words (keys)
print(embeddings.files)

# get embeddings for some specific word
print(embeddings['done'])
```

Comment: thank you so much, but how to save the embedding to a .txt file like this:                                  
                                                                                                                       
_word1  4.530e-02 -1.170e-02 -1.201e-01  2.439e-01  4.670e-02d_                                                                                                                       **word2  4.530e-02 -1.170e-02 -1.201e-01  2.439e-01  4.670e-02d**

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible to store exactly into a .txt file. I would suggest to use numpy to store embeddings (I updated my answer - pls have a look). Also it is possible to pickle w2v dictionary.

Comment: Even I need what you were looking for. Did you manage to solve ? @Newroz .

Comment: DanyloBaibak got an error when looping through tokenizer.word_index.items()   IndexError: index 100 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 100    Then I found that the length of embeddings is different from the length of tokenizer.word_index.items()